# linux port forwarding between two nics

Tags: iptables, port, nic, forwarding, sip

I have a vicidial server running on suse. I have installed two nic cards. One nic connects to my local network and the other connects to the firewall. The config is as below:
Nic 1 : 192.168.2.21 (local network)
Nic 2 : 172.31.31.21 (to firewall NATed)
I want to route all SIP calls from Nic 1 to Nic 2 which ultimately will route calls to my SIP provider. I will need internet on both the nics. Nic 1 will need internet for yum updates and Nic 2 will need internet to register the SIP provider.
Right now all SIP calls are being route out through Nic 1. How do I route it through Nic 2? I am new to iptables, can iptables help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for this,
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward